mat slider not working properly with dir="rtl"
I want to create a site with arabic support in angular material but when I give dir="rtl" I am facing issues for mat slider. when I click on thumb and drag it thumb goes reverse.
I have tried below solution but it is showing error that Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-slider'.
below is my stackblitz example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/45m3gu-suzg2w?file=src%2Fexample%2Fslider-range-example.html

Try just rotating the slider by 180 degrees, then we need to add the ngModel at the input thumb level, not at the mat-slider level.
Global style:
mat-slider.reverse-slider {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

HTML:
<mat-slider class="reverse-slider">
  <input
    matSliderThumb
    [(ngModel)]="sliderValue"
    [min]="minValue"
    [max]="maxValue"
    [step]="stepValue"
  />
</mat-slider>
<p>Current Value: {{ sliderValue }}</p>

TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Basic slider
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'slider-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'slider-overview-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'slider-overview-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatSliderModule, FormsModule],
})
export class SliderOverviewExample {
  minValue: number = 0;
  maxValue: number = 100;
  stepValue: number = 1;
  sliderValue: number = this.maxValue;
}

Stackblitz Demo

-1. That's not how it's supposed to work. You don't use rtl at all, which is what the question is about. And you will get into trouble if you try to add a thumb label.

According to CSS direction article:

Where possible, authors are encouraged to avoid using the direction
CSS property and use the HTML dir global attribute instead.

If you write <body dir="rtl"> and remove direction in CSS for body and slider, the slider will work.
Also you are not using ngModel correctly. See the mat-slider example.

I have already tried it but it is not working properly when you click and drag the thumb.

Here is stackblitz.

It casue same issue for ltr when you remove dir="rtl".

I don't understand what the issue is. When using rtl, 100 should be on the left and 0 should be on the right, no?

Yes right, but when we remove rtl then it causing the issue on ltr support. it shoud be work on both rtl and ltr.

Have you looked at my stackblitz? It's the same as before, for clarity I added discrete attribute to the slider for a thumb label and changed the default value from 100 to 20. With dir="rtl" the slider goes from right to left, with dir="ltr" or without dir it goes from left to right. So what's the issue? Could you please specify?

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/29170924?key=e203553cba72aca5cbdef09089bed7a2 Please check this video. I just remove dir="rtl" from inspect.

I guess mat-slider does something under the hood when dir="rtl" is present. So removing it in Inspect might not work properly. If you change the code in stackblitz itself and refresh, it works, because it is just a basic slider.

Yes, we need to refresh the page. I need the solution without refresh it shoud work.

Now I get it. I believe it is supported in some way (see this and this), but to be honest I'm still struggling to get it to work properly.
